# Certificate revocation check fails for non-domain guest in spite of accessible CRL

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, crl

When we try to use certificates on computers that are not part of the domain, Windows complains that

> The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.

However, if I manually open the certificate and check the `CRL Distribution Point` property, I see an `ldap:///` URL and an `http://` URL that points to externally-accessible IIS site that hosts the CRLs. Of course, the non-domain-joined client cannot access the `ldap:///` URL, but it can download the CRL from the `http://` link (at least in a browser).

I enabled CAPI logging and I see the event that corresponds to this failed revocation check. The 
`RevocationInfo` section is:

> - RevocationInfo
>
>   [ freshnessTime]  PT11H27M4S
>
>   - RevocationResult The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
>       [ value]  80092013
>   - CertificateRevocationList
>         [ location]  UrlCache
>         [ url] http://*the correct URL*
>         [fileRef]  6E463C2583E17C63EF9EAC4EFBF2AEAFA04794EB.crl
>         [issuerName]  *the name of the CA*

Furthermore, I can see the HTTP request to the correct URL and the server's response (HTTP 304 Not Modified) with Microsoft Network Monitor.

I ran `certutil -verify -urlfetch`, and it seems to show the same thing: the computer recognizes both URLs, tries both, and even though the `http://` link succeeds, returns the same error.

Is there a way to have non-domain-joined clients skip the `ldap:///` link and only check the `http://` one?

Edit:
The `ldap:///` URL is

```
ldap:///CN=<name of CA>,CN=<name of server that is running the CA>,CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=<domain name>?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint
```

The non-domain-joined clients may be on the domain network or on an external network. The `http://` CDP is accessible from the public internet.

Comment: Very good question that I myself have run into and do not know the answer to. I think it might be a bug. Has not been urgent enough for me to open a support case with MS about it though.

Comment: Your only workaround may be re-issuing the certs with *only* the HTTP CDP on them.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I think that an PKI enabled application should check all mentioned CDPs and use the one, it can find. So I would guess that his is a mistake of the client. Which application is using the certificates? Other possibility might be: What does the ldap-URL look like and where are the non-domain-joined client located. Maybe you could setup a fake ldap-system, that provides the CRL.

Comment: @cornelinux The actual client is a WCF program, but `certutil`, the built-in program is exhibiting the same behavior. The WCF client does not explicitly check for CDPs or anything, but the check happens automatically.

Comment: Looking at this (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b8f3a948-2c16-408a-af87-d4b1dbef52b5/crls-for-desktop-clients-not-in-a-domain?forum=winserversecurity) and the third answer by Brian (who probably is Brian Komar), he states, that you should *only* use HTTP in the CDP (no File, no LDAP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After troubleshooting this with Microsoft support, we noticed that the delta CRL was not accessible to the client because IIS's default configuration does not support filenames with the `+` character and delta CRL's end with `+`. After enabling double escaping in IIS, the non-domain-joined client was able to confirm that the certificate had not been revoked.